# Getting connot GET /create, while making POST request in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.post("/create1",(req,resp)=>{
    console.log("server started")
    resp.send("done")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

I should get a

```
send
```

on the

```
 https:// localhost:3000/create,
```

i tried changing port number, but am getting same error

Comment: You create a route for `POST /create1`  but you are executing a `GET /create` request ... So both, your method and your url are wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

**There are 3 reasons for not getting the response.**

1. You named the route as **create1** but you are hitting the API as **create**.
2. You used https. It will be http
3. You have created a **POST** (app.post(...) route but you are calling the route in **GET** method. So, use **Postman** tool, change the method to POST and hit the API.

So, The API would be : `http://localhost:3000/create1` (Hit it in POST method from Postman)

Answer (score 0):

This should go ahead and fix your problem.

```js
app.get("/create",(req, res)=>{
    console.log("server started");
    res.send("done");
})
```